# Entity Framework POCO foreign key assignment is hanging

Tags: entity-framework-4, poco

For simplicity, I have a Database with an Order table and a PaymentMethod table.  It is a one to many relationship.  The Order table has many field describing the order and the PaymentMethod only has an Id and a Name.  I have mapped an Association in EF and there is a Foreign Key in the Order table called "PaymentMethodId".  I have an enum called PaymentMethodType, this is not the issues.  I have tested the same code below without the enum involved.  I have many other tables with the same scenario and have ran into this with one other relationship, but am now only having this problem with this one.

In the code below I create a new order and everything works fine.  If I then later get that same order in my program and try to set the PaymentMethodId to a different value, the program hangs for about 25 seconds.  I have tried to trace the code through the POCO objects and it seems to be looping/setting the PaymentMethod and PaymentMethodId over and over again.  Any suggestions or advice is much appreciated!!!  Please feel free to ask questions on any details I may have left out.  I am using Entity Framework 4.0 with POCO along with SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
        int orderid;
        using (PinotsPaletteEntities context = new PinotsPaletteEntities())
        {
            Order order = new Order();
            //assign other order information
            order.PaymentMethodId = (int)PaymentMethodType.CreditCard;               
            context.Orders.AddObject(order);
            context.SaveChanges();
            orderid = order.Id;
        }

        using (var context = new PinotsPaletteEntities())
        {
            Order order2 = context.Orders
                .Where(x => x.Id == orderid)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            order2.PaymentMethodId = (int)PaymentMethodType.Cash; //hangs here for 25secs
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Are you using POCO T4 template? Can you validate that delay is not caused by some unexpected lazy loading?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `PaymentMethodId` property and set a `PaymentMethod` object?

Comment: I get the same results if I set the PaymentMethod object to null or a good object.  Same thing with PaymentMethodId.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?  I'm running into a nearly identical issue.  I am using the "EF 4.x POCO Entity Generator for C#" extension.

Comment: I am seeing the hang when I have a large number of records (orders in your model) in the table where I'm trying to set the foreign key.  I have around 70,000 records.  With no or few records, there is no perceptible delay.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced problems with setting properties using Entity Framework v4.1 and the "ADO.NET C# POCO Entity Generator" (recently renamed to [EF 4.x POCO Entity Generator for C#](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313)).  My project is written in C# using ASP.NET MVC 3.

The symptoms I had were that changing properties would work fine with a relatively small dataset (several dozen).  After importing records from a legacy system (some 70,000 with several hundred thousand related records), setting a property would essentially hang the application.  Like you, the property I was having problems with is a foreign key to a "type" table.

What was bizarre is that setting some near identical properties would work fine.  And setting the property once would work fine.  But toggling between types would hang the application.

I solved the issue, at least for the time being, by migrating to the newer [EF 4.x DbContext Generator for C#](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7812b04c-db36-4817-8a84-e73c452410a2).  By upgrading via Nuget, this also pulled in the latest version of Entity Framework, which may have also had a hand in fixing the problem.  Migrating to DbContext required minimal code changes.  The generated POCO classes are now very clean, without the pages of "fixup" code that the previous T4 template would create.